# HTML: Charset Meta, can not see Norwegian characters

Tags: html, character-encoding, meta-tags

I've got this in my header (so i can see the norwegian characters, but it does not work.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

I get weird letters on Ø Æ Å.

Here's a screenshot, and i can't figure out why it's not working.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaTKS.jpg

Thx in advance.

Comment: You know, this is actually a webadmin question, not a programming question *per se*.  I'm not going to vote to close to relocate it though, because it is so common and not at all obvious.

Comment: @tchrist: there are 141,542 HTML questions on Stack Overflow. This is where they live.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you have two different charset declarations? You should declare only one encoding - the same as is used in the HTML file. If you saved the file in UTF-8, remove the line with the declaration of ISO-8859-1 charset.

Comment: Yes i saved it in utf-8, but it does not help, i still see the weird characters.

Comment: @Kaizokupuffball The line with `charset=iso-8859-1` is redundant, are you sure you've removed it? Also please make sure the server doesn't send any `Content-Type` HTTP header. The link to problematic website would be helpful to investigate the issue.

Comment: underbyen.puffys.netuser:test    pass:test       click on Meldinger, then i think you will see what i mean.

Comment: @Kaizokupuffball What text editor do you use? In hex editor, I see some weird byte sequences; for example, `0xEF 0xBF 0xBD` which is Unicode character `U+FFFD` - definitely not something you wrote on purpose.

Comment: @Kaizokupuffball At least you know that your file is in UTF-8 and browsers also display it as UTF-8; the `U+FFFD` character is meant to be displayed as `�`. I don't know where these characters are from (does the text come from database?), but this is definitely not an issue at client-side.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the html document with you code editor. It may help[image: convert to utf-8]

Answer (score -1):

The `<meta>` tag is not respected by Apache unless you have an overall server configuration that does not have a default charset (highly unlikely) or you have a `.htaccess` file that disables that. Put this in the directory where the HTML files are that have varying encodings specified by an internal `<meta>` tag:

```
AddDefaultCharset Off
```

Comment: I added the line in the .htaccess file, did not help.

Comment: @Kaizokupuffball: Are you set up to allow for `.htaccess` files?

Comment: Yes i am. I am using .htaccess files to disallow the indexing of directories.

Comment: Well, you might say `AddCharset UTF-8 .html` but that will make everything UTF-8 in that directory.

Comment: Would i add .php if all the files are php?

Comment: That's a different question.  I don't have PHP files. These aren't HTML files? You should have tagged this PHP then.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3318/discussion-between-kaizokupuffball-and-tchrist)

Comment: Meta always takes precedence over the http header, so this is not the solution.

Comment: @Gerben: No that is not true. I can absolutely promise you that in my Apache configuration, the meta is not *NOT PAID ATTENTION TO AT ALL* unless you do as I have said.  Configurations vary.

Comment: @tchrist I stand corrected. I should read the spec first before jumping to conclusions. Just for completeness. The order of precedence is (high to low); http header, BOM, xml declaration, meta, link charset attribute.